# como separar un campo varchar en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente dilema...
tengo un campo ID en mi base de datos, que almacena datos compuestos, con texto y número.
ejemplo
USU1
USU2
.
.
.
USU10

quiero saber si existe alguna manera con sql en que pueda ordenar estos campos y obtener el último (para el ejemplo anterior, quiero que muestre USU10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el formato de `ID` es siempre el mismo, puedes separar la parte numérica, para tratarla como un número y ordenar por este dato de forma separada.

```
 order by convert(substring(ID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                substring(ID, 1, 3)
```

Ejemplo:

```
select T.ID
       from (select 'USU10' as ID union
             select 'USU1' union
             select 'USU2') T
       order by convert(substring(T.ID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER),
                substring(T.ID, 1, 3)
```

Salida:

```
|    ID |
|-------|
|  USU1 |
|  USU2 |
| USU10 |
```

Comment: EXCELENTE!, funciona justo como lo q necesito... hice algunos cambios para adaptar a lo que necesito especificamente, que es buscar el id mayor, por lo cual realice lo siguiente:----- 
```
SELECT myID
FROM MyTabla
ORDER BY CONVERT(substring(myID, 4), UNSIGNED INTEGER) DESC, SUBSTRING(myID, 1, 3) LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Mysql puedes hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Lo que hace es seleccionar el último valor de la tabla al ordenarlos de manera descedente con *DESC* y obtener sólo un registro con *LIMIT 1*.

Comment: esto no funciona, ya que como es un varchar no reconoce el USU10 mayor que USU9, osea el mas grande que selecciona es con esa consulta es USU9... Y lo habia probado de esta forma